# How do I call gles20 continuously in sub thread in unity android plugin

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem in the USB device with camera. And its SDK is special that I can't use webtexture in unity.
So I would like to use gles20 to transport camera image to unity. But the callback is in sub thread and it can't render gles20.
Texture id is always 0.

1. I tried writing glGenTextures in function StartCapture, texture id is not 0 but callback cannot find the texture.
2. I search the solution that the sub thread call main thread. Most of them are Activity.runOnUIThread. But the capture crash and stop immediately.

```cs
public class CameraTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class Listener : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
// init proxy listener
        .........

        public void cameraBytes(long timestamp)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Unity timestamp: " + timestamp);
        }

        public void SetTextureId(int textureId)
        {
            this.textureId = textureId;
            Texture2D externTex = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(640, 480, TextureFormat.RGB565, false, false, (IntPtr)textureId);
            tex2D.UpdateExternalTexture(externTex.GetNativeTexturePtr());
        }

    }

    private void Start()
    {
// init java camera plugin
    .......
    }

// trigger button
    public void OpenCamera(bool isOpen)
    {
        plugin.Call("OpenCamera", isOpen);
    }

    public void StartCapture(bool isCapture)
    {
        plugin.Call("StartCapture", isCapture);
    }
```

```java
public class Plugin {

    private int textureId;
    public Plugin(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

public void InitCameraManager(PluginListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) _listener = listener;


        _dataCallback = new CaptureDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureData(long timestamp, byte[] bytes) {
                Log.d("Data", String.format("timestamp: %d", timestamp));
                _listener.cameraBytes(timestamp);
                Log.d("Camera", "Bytes length: " + bytes.length);

                int[] textures = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
                textureId = textures[0];
                Log.d("Camera", "texture id: " + textures[0]);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

                if (textureId != 0) {
                    Log.d("Camera", "texture id: " + textureId);


                    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
                    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                            GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
                    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

                    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
                    _listener.SetTextureId(textureId);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Camera", "texture is fail to load");
                }

            }
        };

    public void OpenCamera(boolean isOpen) {
    // open device camera and set data callback in camera
    ....
    }

    public void StartCapture(boolean isCapture) {
        // start camera capture data
    }
```